# Vector and matrix comparison in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I have vector with 5 numbers in it, and a matrix of size `6000x20`, so every row has 20 numbers. I want to count how many of the 6000 rows contain *all* values from the vector.

As the vector is a part of a matrix which has 80'000'000 rows, each containing unique combinations, I want a fast solution (which doesn't take more than 2 days).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at functions like `ismember`?

Comment: A direct `ismember`-approach with the given sizes will take approximately 10.2h on my i5. I suggest you check out the documentation [here](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). The result can be summed up per row and then be compared to the length of the vector. Finally sum up all the occurrences where the above statement is true.

Comment: Is there a limitation on the range of values?

Comment: Yes, there is, range is from 1 to 80. Does it changes something?

Answer (score 0):

With the sizes you have, a [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)-based approach that builds an intermediate 6000x20x5 3D-array is affordable:

```
v = randi(9,1,5); %// example vector
M = randi(9,6000,20); %// example matrix
t = bsxfun(@eq, M, reshape(v,1,1,[]));
result = sum(all(any(t,2),3));
```